# excecute a java class file using php script

Tags: php, mysql

I am using a java file to generate a report. It is located on my local hard disk. When I call it using cmd prompt it produces output. I want to run this java file using php file.

The lines in cmd are

```
D:\>cd class
D:\>class> java Reportgeneration username password id date
```

These lines are used to execute the java file, how can I execute this code in a php script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP's [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) does the trick. Read the manual!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) function in php to execute command line statements and get back results. You could also use [system](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php)

exec() is for calling a system command, and perhaps dealing with the output yourself. system() is for executing a system command and immediately displaying the output.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [string shell_exec (string $cmd)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php%20%22%22) It allowes you to execute a command in your shell and return the output as a string for furter processing in PHP.

```
<?php
  $output = shell_exec('ls -lart');
  echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

If you have more than one shell command to execute, put them in a .bat file and call teh bat file instead.

Remember that PHP needs the privileges to access the directory and the right to execute.